# Extracting values from an array using snowflake not able to select data in array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

---my data dont have double quotes ,is the reason below array query not working.Please help me how i can select data from following data.
----Not working ------

```
WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) as json
    FROM VALUES 
       ('[
     {
     'type': 'Custom Interaction', 'nb choice': '', 'responseIdentifier': 'RESPONSE', 'BR_identifier': '', 'BR_label': ''
     },
     {
     'type': 'Custom Interaction', 'nb choice': '', 'responseIdentifier': 'RESPONSE_1', 'BR_identifier': '', 'BR_label': ''
     }
     ]'
    )
 )
 select 
    f.value:responseIdentifier as "responseIdentifier" 
 from fake_data d, 
 TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json(d.json))) f;
```

----working after replacing single quotes with double.

```
WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) as json
    FROM VALUES 
    ('[
     {
     "type": "Custom Interaction", "nb choice": "", "responseIdentifier": "RESPONSE", "BR_identifier": "", "BR_label": ""
     },
     {
     "type": "Custom Interaction", "nb choice": "", "responseIdentifier": "RESPONSE_1", "BR_identifier": "", "BR_label": ""
     }
     ]'
    )
 )
 select 
    f.value:responseIdentifier as "responseIdentifier" 
 from fake_data d, 
 TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json(d.json))) f;
```

Comment: Your first set of data isn't working, because it's not appropriate json and the way you are showing the sql, it's not valid SQL, either, since you aren't escaping your single quotes in your string.  Can you provide more details about the source of data itself and what you are attempting to do with it?

Comment: I have a table which has data in table and one of column as data like --[{'type': 'Graphic hotspot', 'nb choice': 4, 'responseIdentifier': 'RESPONSE', 'BR_identifier': 'hotspot_7', 'BR_label': '', 'choice_identifier_1': 'hotspot_5', 'choice_label_1': '', 'choice_identifier_2': 'hotspot_6', 'choice_label_2': '', 'choice_identifier_3': 'hotspot_7', 'choice_label_3': '', 'choice_identifier_4': 'hotspot_8', 'choice_label_4': ''}]  I need to extract data for each value in select query.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is as you show it in the first blob of SQL: aka there are single quotes, and you want to make test example so you can "test" you SQL logic, just escape the quotes to get it valid the SQL, aka you can experiment with this:

```
WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) as json
    FROM VALUES 
       ('[
     {
     \'type\': \'Custom Interaction\', \'nb choice\': \'\', \'responseIdentifier\': \'RESPONSE\', \'BR_identifier\': \'\', \'BR_label\': \'\'
     },
     {
     \'type\': \'Custom Interaction\', \'nb choice\': \'\', \'responseIdentifier\': \'RESPONSE_1\', \'BR_identifier\': \'\', \'BR_label\': \'\'
     }
     ]'
    )
 )
 select 
    f.value:responseIdentifier as "responseIdentifier" 
 from fake_data d, 
 TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json(d.json))) f;
```

gives:

| responseIdentifier |
| --- |
| "RESPONSE" |
| "RESPONSE_1" |

Aka, `PARSE_JSON` does not care about the quote type, but the SQL Parser very much does.

```
create database test;
create schema test.test;
use test.test;

create table table_as_string as
    SELECT column1 as str
    FROM VALUES 
       ('[
     {
     \'type\': \'Custom Interaction\', \'nb choice\': \'\', \'responseIdentifier\': \'RESPONSE\', \'BR_identifier\': \'\', \'BR_label\': \'\'
     },
     {
     \'type\': \'Custom Interaction\', \'nb choice\': \'\', \'responseIdentifier\': \'RESPONSE_1\', \'BR_identifier\': \'\', \'BR_label\': \'\'
     }
     ]'
    );

create table table_as_json as
    SELECT parse_json(column1) as json
    FROM VALUES 
       ('[
     {
     \'type\': \'Custom Interaction\', \'nb choice\': \'\', \'responseIdentifier\': \'RESPONSE\', \'BR_identifier\': \'\', \'BR_label\': \'\'
     },
     {
     \'type\': \'Custom Interaction\', \'nb choice\': \'\', \'responseIdentifier\': \'RESPONSE_1\', \'BR_identifier\': \'\', \'BR_label\': \'\'
     }
     ]'
    );
```

Now we have two tables, one with a string that has quotes inside the string, and another that has json.

We can now parse the String as JSON and use that OR use the JSON as it is:

```
 select 
    f.value:responseIdentifier as "responseIdentifier" 
 from table_as_string d, 
 TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json(d.str))) f;
```

```
  select 
    f.value:responseIdentifier as "responseIdentifier" 
 from table_as_json d, 
 TABLE(FLATTEN(input => d.json)) f;
```

At this point, just like you, we have "data in a table" and "can access it as structured JSON". Where the gap, in example/expection is, I cannot guess.

Comment: my data is in a field of table which as single quotes, I want to select data from that column and parse in fields.

Comment: you are right PARSE_JSON does not care about the quote type. I am able to select data from table for table for above data but for below data not able to do query not sure what's making snowflake upset.

Comment: you are right PARSE_JSON does not care about the quote type. I am able to select data from table for table for above data but for below data not able to do query not sure what's making snowflake upset. record contain Mathematical Markup Language.

Comment: select 
    f.value:responseIdentifier as "responseIdentifier" 
 from table_as_string d, 
 TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json(d.str))) f; is working on table with single quotes in data.