# Mathematical Markup Language contain data not able to parse in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not able to do query on below data not sure what's making snowflake upset. record contain Mathematical Markup Language.

```
 [{'type': 'Choice', 'nb choice': 4, 'responseIdentifier': 'RESPONSE', 'BR_identifier': 'A', 'BR_label': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abctesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abc-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b147eb1d28071779175b6a6b4afae"" alt=""M07_XX01_10398_G07_A_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_1': 'A', 'choice_label_1': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abctesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abc-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b147eb1d28071779175b6a6b4afae"" alt=""M07_XX01_10398_G07_A_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_2': 'B', 'choice_label_2': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abctesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abc-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b1706d6a27736d17112391d143a4d"" alt=""M07_XX01_10398_G07_B_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_3': 'C', 'choice_label_3': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abctesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abc-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b16400aa31403586561c63dc0c123"" alt=""M07_XX01_10398_G07_C_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_4': 'D', 'choice_label_4': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abctesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abc-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b162a71d264684cca5b0f862ceeba"" alt=""M07_XX01_10398_G07_D_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>'}]
    )
 )
```

### Not working

```
 WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) as json
    FROM VALUES 
    (    
 [{'type': 'Choice', 'nb choice': 4, 'responseIdentifier': 'RESPONSE', 'BR_identifier': 'A', 'BR_label': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b147eb1d28071779175b6a6b4afae"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_A_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_1': 'A', 'choice_label_1': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b147eb1d28071779175b6a6b4afae"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_A_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_2': 'B', 'choice_label_2': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b1706d6a27736d17112391d143a4d"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_B_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_3': 'C', 'choice_label_3': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b16400aa31403586561c63dc0c123"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_C_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>', 'choice_identifier_4': 'D', 'choice_label_4': '<p>\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b162a71d264684cca5b0f862ceeba"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_D_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>'}]
    )
 )
 select 
    to_char(f.value:responseIdentifier) as "responseIdentifier" 
 from fake_data d, table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f;
```

WITH fake_data AS (
SELECT
to_json(
[{'type': 'Choice', 'nb choice': 4, 'responseIdentifier': 'RESPONSE', 'BR_identifier': 'A', 'BR_label': '

\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b147eb1d28071779175b6a6b4afae"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_A_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class="""">\n

', 'choice_identifier_1': 'A', 'choice_label_1': '

\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b147eb1d28071779175b6a6b4afae"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_A_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class="""">\n

', 'choice_identifier_2': 'B', 'choice_label_2': '

\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b1706d6a27736d17112391d143a4d"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_B_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class="""">\n

', 'choice_identifier_3': 'C', 'choice_label_3': '

\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b16400aa31403586561c63dc0c123"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_C_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class="""">\n

', 'choice_identifier_4': 'D', 'choice_label_4': '

\n              <img src=""abcdmedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_abcdtesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_abcd-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b162a71d264684cca5b0f862ceeba"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_D_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class="""">\n

'}]
) f
)
select
*
from
fake_data;

Comment: Try opening and closing your string with $$ instead of single quotes. If it still has issues, please update your question to include the first part of your query (it got cut off) so that others can try to reproduce and fix.

Comment: What you have appears not to be valid json (according to a number of online validators) so you need to fix it to make it valid json before Snowflake can process it as json

Comment: @GregPavlik with $$ query is working but not sure how I can read from table column. 
     SELECT $${ "BR_label": 'img src=""taomedia://mediamanager/http_2_www_0_taotesting_0_com_1_ontologies_1_tao-deploy-test-package_0_rdf_3_i60a67b147eb1d28071779175b6a6b4afae"" alt=""M07_AA01_10398_G07_A_v3.svgz"" width=""55%"" type=""image/svg+xml"" class=""""></img>\n            </p>' }
 $$ as json_str
,PARSE_JSON(json_str) as json;

Comment: This is the same question, and technically a worse form of it, to yesterdays question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882781/extracting-values-from-an-array-using-snowflake-not-able-to-select-data-in-array/75883502

Comment: I suspect the GAP is, data in a table is VERY different so "typing data into SQL editor" and they are not identical. So most the answers are showing you how to process your data "as it is, so it can be done in the editor" and those changes will not work on your table based data.

Comment: Wish I read these comments prior to answering.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim ---following query working on table with single quotes                                                   
     select 
    f.value:responseIdentifier as "responseIdentifier" 
 from table_as_string d, 
 TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json(d.str))) f       where as another giving error -- without json parse --error --invalid type [VARCHAR(16777216)] for parameter 'input'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882781/extracting-values-from-an-array-using-snowflake-not-able-to-select-data-in-array/75883502

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882781/extracting-values-from-an-array-using-snowflake-not-able-to-select-data-in-array?noredirect=1#comment133848176_75882781   ---is working  now but this is different data contain forward slash and mathematical markup language. though with below query i am able to parse data but still looking for table query.

Comment: Working--WITH fake_data AS (
SELECT  to_json
<data as above>) f)select *from  fake_data d;